# Any way to avoid dot-slash when running executable scripts in bash?

Tags: linux, mac, bash, terminal

let's say I have a script.

```
chmod +x myscript
```

Now to run this I go

```
./myscript
```

But is there any way I could just run it by typing

```
myscript
```

???

Comment: What OS (distro) are you using?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had same issue and seems no answer till now answers to the question clearly.

The solution to the question is to add `export PATH=.:$PATH` to your `.bash_profile`. This will include the current directory to the unix search path while it searches for the command. It is also wise to have yourself informed about the [security risks](http://www.linfo.org/dot_slash.html) of doing so.

Comment: I might suggest putting "." at the end, rather than the beginning, of the PATH.  At least would help with name collisions.  Cheers.

Answer (score 7):

add the path of the directory where your script is located to the PATH variable:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/directory
```

Answer (score 4):

create symbolic link of script file in any /bin/ ,  /usr/bin  etc.

```
ln -s /path_to_script/myscript /usr/bin/myscript
```

Answer (score 2):

```
export PATH=/path_to_folder_containing_executable/:$PATH
```

If you don't want to run that every time you open a new terminal, you could always add that line into your `~/.bashrc`.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Put the script in `~/bin`, a `bin` directory in your home directory. Then check that `~/bin` is added to your `PATH`. It may be already (though you may have to logout and back in).

You can change your PATH to include `.`, but this is dangerous. It can lead to security problems. E.G.

The most obvious.
**If you set PATH to look in `.` first: then if a directory `a` has an executable file `ls` that does something bad. Then you type `cd a; ls`. Then something bad happens.**

I can only remember a convenience case.
If you set PATH to look in `.` last: You then make a program called `test`, when you run it nothing seems to happen (this is because it is running a `test` that has higher priority, and has no output, just an exit code). There can also be a problem too, if new software is installed, this new software can mask your program (though this one is no different to having `~/bin` at end of PATH).

I have to directories in my home: `~/bin` at end of PATH and `~/bin/override` at beginning of PATH. ~/bin/override` is mostly empty.

Comment: The reason a program in your PATH named `test` doesn't run is because `test` is also the name of a shell builtin.

Comment: @garyjohn yes you see why it can be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using bash, You can run a script without "." by passing the path to the script as argument to bash.

So for example:

```
bash -c /Users/you/myscript.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

All the other answers posted before this one are correct.  (Although
the ones that don't mention `~/.bashrc` are incomplete in that regard.) 
But, if you prefer not to use them, here's an alternative:

Type:

```
alias myscript="/path_to_folder_containing_executable/myscript"
```

or

```
myscript() { /path_to_folder_containing_executable/myscript "$@"; }
```

The second one (which is called a "shell function") can be typed

```
myscript() {
        /path_to_folder_containing_executable/myscript "$@"
}
```

if you prefer.  All of these define `myscript` to be a special type of command
that gets checked before the shell looks at `$PATH`.

Like the `export` commands in the other answers,
these affect only the current shell session. 
To make the effect persistent, put the command into your `~/.bashrc`.